# How can I tab-complete umount, restricting to volumes in a specific directory?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I use zsh with `zim`, which is generally excellent. Ideally, I'd want to umount's tab completion to only suggest items in `/run/media/$USER`. In the following example, this is a single volume named `L_drive`.

```
$ cd /run/media/sparhawk
$ ls
L_drive
$ umount <Tab>
 -- device label --
binfmt_misc  debugfs      fusectl      mqueue       run          systemd-1                          
cgroup       dev          gvfsd-fuse   proc         securityfs   tmpfs                              
configfs     devpts       hugetlbfs    pstore       sys                                           
 -- device path --
/dev/sda2                 /dev/sdb5                 /dev/sdb6                 /dev/sdc1               
 -- mount point --
/                                 /run/media/sparhawk/L_drive       /sys/fs/cgroup/pids             
/dev                              /run/user/1000                    /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd          
/dev/hugepages                    /run/user/1000/gvfs               /sys/fs/fuse/connections        
/dev/mqueue                       /sys                              /sys/fs/pstore                  
/dev/pts                          /sys/fs/cgroup                    /sys/kernel/config              
/dev/shm                          /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio              /sys/kernel/debug               
/HDD                              /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct        /sys/kernel/security            
/home                             /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset             /tmp                            
L_drive                           /sys/fs/cgroup/devices            /var/cache                      
/proc                             /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer            /var/log                        
/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc          /sys/fs/cgroup/memory             /var/tmp                        
/run                              /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls
```

There is a lot of stuff there that I'd never want to tab complete. I'd like to remove all these suggestions, and only leave tab completion for the absolute path `/run/media/sparhawk/L_drive`.

FWIW zim has the following [bug](https://github.com/zimframework/zim/issues/3) where the relative path is not found after typing a letter.

```
$ umount L<Tab>
 -- no matches found --
```

but assuming I can remove all the other suggestions, leaving only the absolute path in `/run/media/$USER/*`, then this bug is moot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ignored-patterns` style](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignored_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style) to exclude some completions.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:umount:*' ignored-patterns "^/run/media/$USER/*"
```

Under the default settings, you can still get completion for ignored patterns if there is no non-ignored candidate.

(This answer is for plain zsh using the `compinit` completion system. It's possible, but unlikely, that zim somehow causes it not to work.)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! (There was a small typo that had to be fixed for it to work.)